# useState hook does not update inside setTimeout function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout, use-state

this code must increase the "count" value gradually from 0 to 600. And each time the "count" value changes it must be logged into the console. But instead, I get the "count" value consoled from 6 to 15 times. So the "count" value updates scarcely 20 times instead of desired 600. What might be the problem with this code?

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(count);
}, [count]);

const startCount = () => {
  for(let i = 0, i < 600, i++)
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCount(prev => prev + 1);
    }, i);
  };
};
```

Comment: you create 600 timeouts at the same time, maybe that's not the best way to do it. Instead create the new timeout each time a previous timeout has finished, then they can all have a wait time of 1.

Comment: what do you mean by "gradually"? this looks rather un gradual like. also your for loop definition looks wrong `(let i = 0; i < 600; i++)`. You're probably also only seeing the "change" logged 20 times because the render cycle cant keep up with the rate at which count is changing.

Answer (score 1):

`useState` is operating as intended. See ["Batching of state updates"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#batching-of-state-updates)

Your `startCount` function is setting things up to update the count *every millisecond* for the next 600 milliseconds. The state is updating, but probably much faster than you intended (you said "gradually" so I suspect you intended one update per second). And since it's updating faster than your browser is going to be able to re-render your component, the state updates are being batched. Since your `console.log` is tied to the rendering cycle via `useEffect`, it only runs when your component re-renders.

By the way, `setInterval` would be much better to use than `setTimeout` here since it's intended for repeatedly calling a function at some regular time interval.

```js
const [isCounting, setCounting] = useState(false)
const startCounting = () => setCounting(true)

const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

// the function within will run when the component mounts,
// and when `isCounting` changes
useEffect(() => {
  // don't want to do anything if we're not "counting"
  if (isCounting) {
    // set up the periodic function call here
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(prev => {
        if (prev < 600) {
          // "counting" increment
          return prev + 1
        } else {
          // turn off the periodic call if we reach 600
          clearInterval(interval)
          return 600
        }
      })
    }, 500)

    // if `isCounting` changes again, react will call the "cleanup" function
    // that you return from useEffect, before calling the new useEffect function
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }
}, [isCounting])
```

Answer (score 0):

1. When you set new state component re-renders
2. Every time the component re-renders it starts a new loop.
3. loop sets a new state, which will cause re-render which will start step-1.

**This will cause an infinite loop.**

You can achieve a count from 0-n like below.

```
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(count);
    if (count <= 600) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setCount((prev) => prev + 1);
      }, count);
    }
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz! {count}</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that the `for loop` executes `600` times & **batches** `600` state updates within the next `interval` which is `i`.

If you increase the `setTimeout` interval to 2000 you would see a 2 second delay & then there would be a quick 600 state updates.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const interval = 2000;
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(count);
  }, [count]);

  const startCount = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setCount((prev) => prev + 1);
      }, interval);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>{count}</h3><button onClick={startCount}>Start (interval {interval})</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
      <App/>,
      document.getElementById("react")
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
 <div id="react">
```